# Resize image in xaml without losing quality

Tags: c#, image, xaml

I have this image (original size: 256x256)

[image]

I made this xaml definition to show the image in my application

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" 
       Source="/MyProject;component/Images/happy.png" 
       Stretch="Fill" 
       Width="64" Height="64"  
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

And I get this result

[image]

How can I made a more smooth resize?

Comment: You're looking for Vector Graphics, as opposed to bitmaps.

Comment: All of these answers below might produce a higher quality image, but @HighCore is correct in that you should be using Vector, not Bitmap images.

Comment: @HighCore is there a way to take a bitmap and convert it to Vector Graphics ?

Comment: @eranotzap see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19729356/643085), which points to [this tool](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/). Didn't try it myself, but a quick glance suggests it  produces really good results.

Comment: @eranotzap also, [this tool](http://vectormagic.com/home)

Comment: Since the image is being scaled DOWN (reduced in total number of pixels) there is relatively little advantage in using a vector source, it's just confusing the issue. There is also very little point attempting to use a bitmap to vector conversion tool, you can never increase the amount of information already in the image.

Comment: @HighCore: As pointed out in the comment above, vector graphics are nice, if you want to scale **up**. When scaling down, a bitmap is just fine, as long as you apply appropriate filtering (bi-linear, bi-cubic, etc.). Dogmatic cry for *"vector graphics"* whenever you hear the term *"scaling"* isn't helpful, unless you explain why this would help. Good advice always comes with a rationale, so that you know when good advice turns bad.

Comment: The accepted answer on this question is simply wrong. Vector resizing is obviously the preferred option, but this is often not possible. So, raster resizing is necessary. However, WPF seems to do a very poor job of this even on HighQuality or Fant. I use UWP, and Silverlight. These platforms don't have any scaling issues, but WPF's rendering engine looks like garbage. Even when I put a simple image on the screen with one line pixels, it renders the line two pixels thick. What is wrong with WPF? How do we fix it?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Include `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"` on your Image, like so:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1"
       Source="/MyProject;component/Images/happy.png"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
       Stretch="Fill"
       Width="64"
       Height="64"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Margin="0,0,0,0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: +1 for naming `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode`. "NearestNeighbor" provided the best results for me

Comment: Melbourne, did you set UseLayoutRounding=true on the form or SnapToDevicePixels=true on the control? If not, it will "blur" the image between device pixels.

Answer (score 63):

Set `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` property for your `Image` through `.xaml`:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" ... />
```

**Additional info:**

The `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` is a property that scales the images based on the quality.
WPF 4.0 defaults it to `Unspecified`, which refers to `LowQuality` image rendering.

But to ensure that the image remains good quality when the size increases, BitmapScalingMode
should be chosen as `HighQuality`.

Here is **BitmapScalingMode** Enumeration members with their description from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode):

> 1.*Fant* - Use very high quality Fant bitmap scaling, which is slower than all other bitmap scaling modes, but produces higher quality
>   output.
>
> 2.*HighQuality* - Use high quality bitmap scaling, which is slower than LowQuality mode, but produces higher quality output. The HighQuality
>   mode is the same as the Fant mode.
>
> 3.*Linear* - Use linear bitmap scaling, which is faster than HighQuality mode, but produces lower quality output.
>
> 4.*LowQuality* - Use bilinear bitmap scaling, which is faster than HighQuality mode, but produces lower quality output. The LowQuality
>   mode is the same as the Linear mode.
>
> 5.*NearestNeighbor* - Use nearest-neighbor bitmap scaling, which provides performance benefits over LowQuality mode when the software
>   rasterizer is used. This mode is often used to magnify a bitmap.
>
> 6.*Unspecified* - Use the default bitmap scaling mode, which is Linear.

Comment: "But to ensure that the image remains good quality when the size increases" --> it's not only when size increase, but also for other image manipulations such as rotation or scaling (up or down). There's in theory a performance impact on using HighQuality, but with current hardware it should become the default. This results in a huge quality difference as it seems to activate antialiasing.

Answer (score 7):

As answered above, the setting `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"` activates the antialiasing. I'd like to provide an example for users who don't know what antialiasing is.

Without this setting :

```
<Image x:Name="InstrumentImage" />
```

[image: With BitmapScalingMode]

With this setting :

```
<Image x:Name="InstrumentImage" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
```

[image: Without BitmapScalingMode]

See the different options here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode?view=netframework-4.8