# PSD to WPF XAML: Import is messed up

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, photoshop, blend

I'm having a Designer come up with some elements in Photoshop, which I then plan to use to build an app in Visual Studio. When I try to import the PSD file into Blend, it's a nightmare though.

Having made most elements using clipping masks, I can either merge them and have it look the same in XAML, but then I lose all the editing options as it's just one big block. If I don't merge the layers, I have the elements imported without the clipping mask which just looks horrible.

I know the import doesn't actually support clipping masks (seriously...?), so what's the best approach here? I'm sure I'm not the first one with this problem, however I can't seem to find ANYTHING on the web regarding a solution.

Should the PSD be changed or is the a way to change something during import?

Thanks a lot,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your designer is making your assets in Photoshop than you're going to run into all sorts of issues especially once you start dealing in the varying possible resolutions etc, which you'll end up trying to counter with things like embedding the image files into `ViewBox` etc. There's not as much flexibility in usability with that route.

My suggestion, would be unless it's really necessary to use Photoshop assets in your work, create your assets in Illustrator instead and use an export to Actual Pure XAML converter like [Mike Swansons AI to XAML tool](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) (which is quite handy) then you'll be dealing with real XAML and vectors so you can take those assets and do a lot more with them in regards to things like Transforms, Storyboards, Property changes, etc. Plus it will all be vectored art so you can play with sizes /shapes to your hearts content and not lose the crisp lines and resolution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll ask him about Illustrator, although given that we're already quite into the project, this will be a problem. Is there a way to convert from PS to Illustrator?

Comment: Well therein lies part of your dilemma, PS is awesome for what it does with `Raster` images. Works great for making things like websites to chop up and throw together. Except if you're working with WPF you're going to find `Vector` image assets generally the way to go. You can find different sites etc on google for raster to vector conversion but I haven't found one worth anything. If one ends up working well for you be sure to post it back here. :)

Comment: Ok, will do surely if I find something :)

Comment: Hey Chris I know this is an old question, but thought I would add a mention of something kind of related. There's an Adobe tool called Fireworks (no longer developed but still obtainable) that is a mixture between Photoshop and Illustrator. It is useful for UI work and might add some value in your situation. Still wish Adobe would take it forward. Check out this XAML extension: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/fireworks/articles/fw_xaml_panel.html Still works as at date of this comment.

Comment: @GrahamMc Ah sure, ya I remember Fireworks. Used to use it quite a bit for that purpose but eventually I found the separation between vector/raster via ai/ps produced better results at least for my circumstances. Good point in sharing for others though, I'm sure it could be a handy tip. Cheers :)

Comment: You can also create an Svg image file from illustrator and use SvgToXaml from github.
https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml